# Can the server know my IP address via Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ip-address

I just want to know whether the server which I am browsing can know my IP address or not ?

I am not doing any thing illegal I am just operating a blog, and I don't want anyone to know who is operating the blog.

Lets assume that the blog hosting owner (or server admin) is willing to find my IP address; can he find it? 
(I use Tor Browser all the time)

Answer (score 2):

When using Tor, the server should only see the IP from the Tor exit node.

However, your IP could still be leaked in various ways, such as using the same account with and without Tor, using plug-ins such as Flash Player, and so on.

This page has a good overview of how Tor works: https://www.torproject.org/about/overview